# Embed a map with satellite terrain active (iframe)

Tags: google-maps, iframe

I have this iframe, generated in Google Maps.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1ssxg5qgL8pDlVKV4Jcc4axK_O9s2DYm2&ehbc=2E312F" width="100%" height="480"></iframe>
```

I would like to know if it is possible force the map to be displayed with the satellite image activated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you need to change it in MyMaps before you create the embedded `<frame>`.  See: http://www.geocodezip.com/SO_20220206_embeddedSat.html

[image: screenshot of example]

The top map is your original, the bottom map is a copy with the base map changed "satellite".

To change the base map, click on "Base Map" in the left hand menu:
[image: screenshot of left menu]

Then choose the image of the satellite tiles:

[image: screenshot of satellite choice]

Then share and capture the new embedded `<iframe>` with a potentially new URL (might actually be the same).